# IEnumerable.Average() causing error or is it simple mathematics?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<double>() { 115.76000213623, 118.470001220703, 116.049995422363, 115.76000213623, 118.470001220703, 116.049995422363 };

    var avg1 = list.Average();
    HashSet<double> hash = new HashSet<double>();

    foreach(var m in list)
        hash.Add(m);

    var avg2 = hash.Average();
}
```

I have a list of double which ranges from 10,000 to 10,000,000. In a specific phase of my application, i have to remove duplicates from this list but in that case the "average" never matches with the original raw list.

What I am expecting is `3+6/2 = 4.5` will always be same as `3+3+6+6/4 = 4.5`

Comment: `3+6/2` is not equal to 4.5, but equal to 6. You should use parenthesis like: `(3+6)/4`. This is basic math: http://math.about.com/library/weekly/aa040502a.htm

Comment: Most likely floating point rounding error. You need to compare the doubles with some threshold.

Comment: When you say duplicates, do you mean a list with each element duplicated?

Comment: '(2 + 1 + 1 + 1) / 4 = 5/4', but '2/1 = 2'. So you're thinking wrong

Comment: Average remains the same when you remove elements that are equal to the average. Otherwise it may or may not change. Without any guarantees.

Comment: @Max 3+6/3 is just for illustration. Actual calculation is being done in IEnumerable.Average()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a mathematics issue. For instance if you had `{3, 3, 3, 7 }` the average would be

```
(3+3+3+7)/4=4
```

If you remove the duplicates ( the numbers that are the same ), `{3, 7}` :

```
(3+7)/2=5
```

So in if you remove the duplicate, you will create a list of the distinc numbers in the initial list and then calling the `Average` you will get the average of the numbers of this list and not the average of the numbers of the initial list.

In some cases, you will get the same value, but that would be a coincidence and not a rule.

Comment: In the example, it is more like `(3+7+3+7)/4`, i.e. all elements duplicated once.

Comment: @Rotem I assume that's a case in the mind of OP's meaning that this don't exclude cases like the one I mentioned in my asnwer.

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see how this is the answer. OP specifically gave test code, for which this is not the reason of failure.

Comment: The OP gave an instance of his problem. However the nature of his problem is more general. Please let's take another approach. Let that his argument is correct. In my answer I have reffered one instance of our problem that brokes his argument -removing the duplicates, doesn't affect the average-. So this argument is not any more correct. If you remove the duplicates the average would be affected.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I think the problem should be divided in two depending on what exactly OP meant.

Comment: @Rotem I agree with you since that will clear any ambiguous points. However, I feel that the above answer answers to the question the OP would originally wanted to post.

Answer (score 0):

Let's differentiate between two cases:

1) You remove elements from the set whose average is NOT equal to the average of the whole set - as a result the average of the remaining subset will be different - see @Christos answer.

2) You remove elements from the set whose average IS equal to the average of the whole set (as in your example code). In this case the culprit is [floating point rounding error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error). This can be more easily shown using this example code.

```
double val = 0.123456789101112;
double a = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Average(i => val);
double b = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Average(i => val);
a == b; //false!
```

You must compare the values using some threshold as such:

```
Math.Abs(a-b) < threshold;
```